# count() vs count = count + 1 in Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am creating a like comment and reply feature using Flask. I have two options:

1. if a user likes comment, variable will increase by 1, Code: `like = like + 1`, and it will be updated in the database. The total count will be retrieved by something like {{ like }} in jinja template

or

2. Saving yes for the comment id in the database, then use `.count()` to retrieve the total likes.

Which would you recommend and why, thank you!

Comment: i would use like = like + 1, easier calculations

Comment: Time complexity wise, like = like + 1 is better because retrieval is O(1) where as the count() is O(n). But if you ever what to know who liked what you don't have that information with like = like + 1

Comment: @Macattack you mean using .count() will be slower?

Comment: This gets to the heart of SQL vs NOSQL. The NOSQL camp would favor option 2 - just log likes (and a bunch of other things) and use a map/reduce framework to do the counting.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert but I think if you have the like and unlike button then you just do

`like = like + 1 #in case of like`

`like = like - 1 #in case of unliking`

Because the .count() function works in a Time complexity of O(length of yes's array) but if you always updated you can access the like count in O(1)